# Is it possible to use an EF4 EntityConnection in a SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sqlconnection

For instance:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(efContext.Connection...?)
connection.Open();

etc..
```

Comment: Do you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576067/entity-framework-objectcontext-raw-sql-calls-to-native-dbms ?

Comment: @a1ex07 That question was for an older version of EF and PostGres...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not directly, no, but you can get the Sql connection string from it, and create a new connection using the `StoreConnection` property:

```
SalesSyncEntities ctx = new SalesSyncEntities();
    EntityConnection ec = (EntityConnection)ctx.Connection;
    SqlConnection sc = (SqlConnection)ec.StoreConnection;
    string adoConnStr = sc.ConnectionString;
    return adoConnStr;
```

Found [here](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2009/11/getting-sqlconnection-from.html).

Comment: No need to upcast it, DbConnection has a `ConnectionString` member.

Comment: @Motton, this didn't work for me.  The ConnectionString property of the DbConnection object (ctx.Connection in the example above) only had this value: "name=MyEntities".  I had to traverse it just as @Behrens showed.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Entity Framework's connection strings specify the model files as well as the underlying store connection; this is not a format understood by SQL Server.