# MVC 4 - Reporting Service and Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I'm using MVC4 and Entity Framework in order to develop an intranet web app and one of the requirements is that the app will be able to create reports. So I'm using Reporting Service to do that.

In my Report File (.rdlc), I have a table which is supposed to contain all the records I have in my table "Persons". I have created a Stored Procedure which gets all the persons from my DB and an action to allow the downloading of the report.

Th thing is, I have no idea about how to tell my action that my data source is my stored procedure.

Here is my Action :

```
public ActionResult PersonReport()
{

    ReportViewer personReportViewer = new ReportViewer();

    List<ReportParameter> reportParameters = new List<ReportParameter>();

    reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Title", "Test"));

    personReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);

    personReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    personReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = 
       HttpContext.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Reporting\\Templates\\"
        + "PersonReport.rdlc";

    byte[] byteArray = personReportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");

    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
         "attachment; Filename=\"" + DateTime.Now + "_Title_" + "\"");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Binary");
    Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And here is my Stored Procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetAllPersons

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT * FROM  bm_Persons;

END
```

Any idea about how to do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you explain "tell my action that my data source is my stored procedure" because that makes no sense to me?

Comment: In fact, when I launch the app and click on the link which is related to my action, it returns an error which tells me that there is no source to fill my table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the procedure and pass the result to ReportViewer.
But how **you** do that it is not possible to answer at the moment. Are you using plain old ADO.NET to connect to your database, or Entity Framework, or NHibernate etc...

Your stored procedure will return a collection of results, so I would assign that to a variable and pass that into the ReportViewer. Or have a method `GetAllPersons` which returns an `Array` or `IList<T>` or other suitable type and then you can use that outside the scope of your method.

Given that you're using EF then in order to get a set of results from your stored procedure you would need a method similar to this that I have taken from [the answer I referred to in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10254855/96505):

```
public static DataSet ExecuteStoredProcedure(ObjectContext db, 
                                             string storedProcedureName, 
                                             IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    var connectionString = 
        ((EntityConnection)db.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString;
    var ds = new DataSet();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }

            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: usually you have a dbContext available that you would use to invoke your procedure. There's this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx that might help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! However, in your static method, there is a parameter which I can't understand what it means (the third one).
When I'll use this method, for the last parameter, what should I pass?

Comment: just pass a `null` in _this_ case. The parameter is a collection of parameters that you could pass through to a stored procedure. In another procedure you might need to pass `StartDate` and `EndDate` for example, in which case you would create a new IEnumerable of SqlParamters and pass that into the method call. As your procedure doesn't have any input parameter you can pass null

Comment: Okay, I think I have understand what you'll explain.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to setup `ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources`:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", startDate)); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", endDate)); 

var thisConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString; 

SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(thisConnectionString); 

cmd.Connection = thisConnection; 

cmd.CommandText = string.Format("[dbo].[StoredProcedureName]"); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 

System.Data.DataSet thisDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet(); 

da.Fill(thisDataSet); 


////////////
/// HERE ///
////////////
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource(rptName, thisDataSet.Tables[0]); 

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); 
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource); 

....................

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any way, there is a problem for me when I'm trying to do like you for the `thisConnectionString, there is an error and VS proposes me to generate the property stub.

Comment: Fixed. It should be string - just connection string to your database.

Comment: Seems that following question describes similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802707/setting-the-datasource-for-a-local-report-net-report-viewer