# EF, how to increase query performance

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

i have about `1 million` data in my database(`MySQL`)

and there's a advancedSearch function which is `very slow`(more than 30 sec), because the SQL EntityFramework generated is not very good, SQL:

```
SELECT
`Project1`.*
FROM 
(
SELECT
`Extent1`.*
FROM `tnews` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`Region` = 'Americas(2)'
 ) AS `Project1`
 ORDER BY 
`Project1`.`PnetDT` DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

C# function:

```
    private List<CNNews> AdvancedSearchAndPage(int pagenum, int pagesize,
        AdvSearchArgs advArgs)
    {
        IQueryable<CNNews> result = _dbRawDataContext.CNNews.
            OrderByDescending(n => n.PnetDT);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advArgs.Feed))
        {
            result = result.Where(news => news.Feed == advArgs.Feed);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advArgs.PNET))
        {
            result = result.Where(news=>news.PNET == advArgs.PNET);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advArgs.ProdCode))
        {
            result = (from news in result
                      where news.ProdCode == advArgs.ProdCode
                      select news);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advArgs.Code))
        {
            result = (from news in result
                      where news.Code == advArgs.Code
                      select news);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advArgs.BegineDate))
        {
            var begin = Convertion.ToDate(advArgs.BegineDate);
            var end = Convertion.ToDate(advArgs.EndDate);

            result = (from news in result
                      where news.PnetDT >= begin && news.PnetDT < end
                      select news);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(advArgs.Region))
        {
            result = result.Where(x => x.Region == advArgs.RegionName);
        }

        var pagedList = result.
            Skip(pagenum * pagesize).
            Take(pagesize);
        return pagedList.ToList();
    }
```

if the SQL format like this, it will `very fast`:

```
 SELECT
*
FROM `tnews` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`Region` = 'Americas(2)'
 ORDER BY 
 `PnetDT` DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your own SQL directly off the DbSet and get all the benefits of EF, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.103).aspx

Also other ways, see these answers for more details

[Is it possible to run native sql with entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915329/is-it-possible-to-run-native-sql-with-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ that generated your query looks something like this:

```
IQueryable<CNNews> result = _dbRawDataContext.CNNews
    .OrderByDescending(n => n.PnetDT)
    .Where(x => x.Region == advArgs.RegionName)
    .Skip(pagenum * pagesize)
    .Take(pagesize);
```

You tell LINQ to select all items and order them. Then you tell it to take a subset of that. The SQL looks exactly like what you have specified, I would say.

If you rearrange your code somewhat so that the `Where()` call is before the `OrderByDescending()` call I think you might get better SQL:

```
IQueryable<CNNews> result = _dbRawDataContext.CNNews
    .Where(x => x.Region == advArgs.RegionName)
    .OrderByDescending(n => n.PnetDT)
    .Skip(pagenum * pagesize)
    .Take(pagesize);
```

Also, I don't know if changing order of `OrderByDescending()` and `Skip()`/`Take()` would give different results.

(Disclaimer: I haven't tested it)

Comment: Yes. What makes you think I haven't?

Comment: Euhm... did you read the question? It certainly sounds like you are asking about performance and the if-clauses have nothing to do with performance.

Comment: that is the problem, u can have a try. look the downstairs answer

Comment: Try this: move the `OrderByDescending()` from the top of the method to the bottom: `IQueryable<CNNews> result = _dbRawDataContext.CNNews;` and `var pagedList = result.OrderByDescending().Skip(...`. This, I think, will improve your performance (and that is what I tried to say in my answer).