# .NET Entity Framework Insert vs Bulk Insert

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When I use my xxxContext object and issue several Adds to a table, then SaveChanges() how does the entity framework resolve this to SQL? Will it just loop doing *insert into xxx* or if there are hundreds of rows, is it smart enough to issue a Bulk insert command?

Bonus Question: If it doesn't issue the Bulk Insert is there a way to force it to so my DB performance isn't killed by separate inserts? Or to bulk to a temp table then merge to the original table like an Upsert?

Comment: Use the SqlBulkCopy API

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Entity framework is very slow for this. Found a way to do it much faster.
Basically you bulk insert into a temp table then issue a merge from there to the main table. I've explained the technique on my blog here:
http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/

Describes the technique and shows the code how to do it.

Comment: To Upsert it's much faster to do this: http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The downfall of any ORM tool is that it is "chatty".  Most times this is good enough.  Sometimes it is not.

The short answer is "no".

Which is why I still sometimes pick IDataReader over EF or NHibernate, etc.
And for bulk insert operations, I send xml to the stored procedure, and I shred it and bulk insert/update or merge from there.

So even when I use an ORM, I create a Domain Library that is not EF (or NHibernate) dependent......so I have a "safety valve" to by pass the ORM in certain situations.

Comment: Thanks, what I thought. Surprised there isn't any OpenSource solution out there that deals with this. My project writes thousands of records at once to the db and this happens every 15 seconds so I guess I'll stick to plain sql where I can control it better.

Comment: Here is the key thing.  The index recreating is the slow-down.  When you insert RBAR (row by agonizing row), you have to recreate the index after every insert.  So you do something "set based", like passing xml, shredding it, then doing a insert into dbo.MyTable select (bunch rows) from something.  Now, you could do some voodoo where you insert into a staging table, and then issue a "move from staging to real" (in a bulk manner), but its not very EF'ish.  But again, the rule of thumb (or one of the main ones) is "how are my indexes being rebuilt when I do it this way".  Aka, the forgotten item

Comment: The majority of what I do is basically an upsert. (update or insert) I need them to be fast and the tables I upsert to have billions (almost trillions) of rows. The fastest approach I've found is inserting to a temp table then doing a merge. I've documented it here: http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

There is oportunity for several improvements in Entity Framework:

Set:

```
yourContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
yourContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Do `SaveChanges()` in packages of 100 inserts... try with 1000 and see the changes.

Since during all this inserts, the context is the same, you can rebuild your context object every 1000 inserts. `var yourContext = new YourContext();`

Doing this improvements in an importing data process of mine, took it from 7 minutes to 6 seconds.

The actual numbers... could not be 100's o 1000's in your case... try it and tweek it.

Comment: I have a fairly complex migration where I'm also using UoW/Repo layer and this saved a significant amount of migration time for me. Not sure I'm able to make use of EntityFramework.BulkInsert given flow of obtaining and saving data in my console app.

Answer (score 3):

If your insert queries are ANSI SQL or you don't care about supporting multipe databases with your codebase, you still have the backdoor to create a ADO.NET provider from EF and execute some raw SQL calls

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1579220/98491

I would do something like this

```
private void BulkInsert(IEnumerable<Person> Persons)
{

    // use the information in the link to get your connection
    DbConnection conn = ...
    using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {

       var sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.Append("INSERT INTO person (firstname, lastname) VALUES ");
       var count = 0;
       foreach(var person in persons)
       {
           if (count !=0) sb.Append(",");
           sb.Append(GetInsertCommand(person, count++, cmd));
       }

       if (count > 0)
       {
           cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
    }



   if (sb.Length > 0)
       ExecuteNonQuery(sb.ToString());
}

private string GetInsertCommand(Person person, int count, DbCommand cmd)
{
    var firstname = "@firstname" + count.ToString();
    var lastname = "@lastname" + count.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(firstname, person.Firstname);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(lastname, person.Firstname);
    return String.Format("({0},{1})", firstname, lastname);
}
```

I must admit I haven't tested it but this should be a quick and dirty method to bypass EF for some Bulk Inserts until Bulk inserts are part of the core.

**Update**

Just a quick idea. Have you tried the ... method from the Migrations namespace?
Maybe this one does bulk inserts, haven't look into it but it is worth a try:

```
private void BatchInsert(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(persons);
}
```

I know this method can be slow if you define a Key column like `AddOrUpdate(p => p.Firstname, persons)` but I would guess without specifing it, that should be all inserts (not guaranteed)

Comment: `AddOrUpdate` without the lambda parameter uses the key property to query, so it's basically identical with `AddOrUpdate(p => p.Id, persons)`. It will still be one query (`SingleOrDefault` by the key) per person in the collection before it inserts.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [bulk insert extension](http://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/)

usage:

```
using EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions;

context.BulkInsert(myEntities);
```

with DbContext:

```
using (var ctx = GetContext())
{
    using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        // some stuff in dbcontext    
        ctx.BulkInsert(entities);    
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid EF does not support bulk insert or update. As you said currently EF will generate bunch of Insert commands and execute them separately (but all wrapped in a single transaction). There were some plans to implement batching, not sure if there is some progress recently. Hopefully in EF6 but I somehow doubt.

You can read more in this [discussion](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/377636).

Answer (score -1):

ASP .NET Core version fast method insert from Repository.

```
public virtual void AddRangeFastAndCommit(IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    MyDbContext localContext = new MyDbContext(_context.Options);
    localContext.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        localContext.Add(entity);
    }

    localContext.SaveChanges();
    localContext.Dispose();
}
```